# Set Dictionary Value to a Class?

Tags: python

Is it possible to set a dictionary value to a class?
Not sure if I'm using a class in the proper manner here but something such as:

```
class ValueClass:

    def __init__(self,foo,foo2,foo3):

        self.foo=foo
        self.foo2=foo2
        self.foo3=foo3 

res={}

with open('foo.txt','r') as lines:

     for line in lines:
         k=line.split()[4]
         foo=line.split()[5]
         foo2=line.split()[6]
         foo3=line.split()[7]
         res[k]=ValueClass
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Why do you want to do that? You're throwing away the values you assign to `foo`, `foo2`, and `foo3`. Do you really want an *instance* of `ValueClass` with those attributes set?

Comment: Maybe the formatting is incorrect here, but it also appears that you're not passing any values to ValueClass. Maybe edit so the last line is `res[k] = ValueClass(foo, foo2, foo3)`?

Answer (score 2):

Using this code, you set `res[k]` to be the type `ValueClass`, not actually an instance of it (which I'm guessing isn't your intention?).

You'd probably want to do this:

```
class ValueClass(object):
   def __init__(self, foo=None, foo2=None, foo3=None):
     self.foo = foo
     self.foo2 = foo2
     self.foo3 = foo3 

res = {}

for line in lines:
  k, foo, foo2, foo3 = line.split()[4:7]
  res[k] = ValueClass()
```

If you want to initialize the class with those values, you can do this:

```
for line in lines:
  k, foo, foo2, foo3 = line.split()[4:7]
  res[k] = ValueClass(foo, foo2, foo3)
```

This lets you set the class's properties afterwards, as you made `res[k]` an *instance* of `ValueClass`.